# C#: System.AccessViolationException while working with GTKSharp

Tags: c#, gtk#

I made an application which communicates with a device. Refresh rate of data from device is 1 second. I wanted the application to be portable so I made GUI using GTKSharp. I am new to GTK so I used what GTK offers and I didn't make anything custom. To design the window, I started with template and then I was using Glade 3.40. The application is working but sometime it throws exception:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at Gtk.Image.set_IconName(System.String)
...
```

The exception appears in 10 minutes of running but the application should be running at least for hours maybe for days.

The exception appears on Windows, on Linux I just tested if app launches, so I cannot confirm the problem there.

Here is simplified code, but I guess it contains everithing required.

```
class MainWindow
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer refreshTimer;
    [UI] private Image? firstIndicator = null;
    // Other 30 images

    public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade"))
    {
    }

    private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetRawOwnedObject("MainWindow"))
    {
        builder.Autoconnect(this);

        refreshTimer = new Timer(refreshTimer_Elapsed);
        refreshTimer.Change(500, 1000);
    }

    private void refreshTimer_Elapsed(object state)
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }

    private bool UpdateValues()
    {
        MyDataType data = device.ReadData(); // For now synchronous reading, but async is in progress

        UiChangeIndicatorState(firstIndicator, data?.firstBoolData);
        // Other 30 indicators
    }

    private void uiChangeIndicatorState(Image target, bool? state)
    {
        const string indFalse = "dialog-error";
        const string indTrue = "dialog-information";
        const string indDisconnected = "dialog-question";

        if (state.HasValue)
            target.IconName = state.Value ? indTrue : indFalse;
        else
            target.IconName = indDisconnected;
    }
}
```

I have tried to make sure that updating values is called on GUI thread with no luck.

```
Threads.AddIdle(0, UpdateValues);
```

I also tried converting reading data async, but that did not help neither. With async I used the `Threads.AddIdle`, I also tried using locks around object MyDataType but that killed the application - refreshing values dropped to once in 5 seconds.

I also tried timer period and it seemed to me that time before exception has exponential dependency on that period. But refresh rate should be 1 second at maximum.

I tried to google the exception but I could not find anything related to GTK. Maybe I am using wrong Google.

Now I switched the images to labels and using "0", "1" and "-" values but it is also not the solution. It is not nice and once it thrown the same exception just `at Gtk.Label.set_Text(System.String)`.

Is the problem inside of a library or is it a problem of my code? I am using nuget package GtkSharp 3.24.24.95 and .NET 7. According to similar questions it seems that it is a problem of C++ library. If it is problem of library then my other question is: If I downgrade the library will it helps and which version is correct?

Comment: Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/issues)

Comment: @HansPassant If I understand you right, then it is a problem of the library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. `Threads.AddIdle(0, UpdateValues);` did the trick, also moving loading data from method `UpdateValues` so the data are not loaded on GUI thread.

```
private readonly System.Threading.Timer refreshTimer;
private readonly MyDataType data;
[UI] private Image? firstIndicator = null;
// Other 30 images

public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade"))
{
}

private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetRawOwnedObject("MainWindow"))
{
    builder.Autoconnect(this);

    refreshTimer = new Timer(refreshTimer_Elapsed);
    refreshTimer.Change(500, 1000);
}

private void refreshTimer_Elapsed(object state)
{
    data = device.ReadData(); // For now synchronous reading, but async is in progress

    Threads.AddIdle(0, UpdateValues);
}

private bool UpdateValues()
{
    UiChangeIndicatorState(firstIndicator, data?.firstBoolData);
    // Other 30 indicators

    return false;
}

private void uiChangeIndicatorState(Image target, bool? state)
{
    const string indFalse = "dialog-error";
    const string indTrue = "dialog-information";
    const string indDisconnected = "dialog-question";

    if (state.HasValue)
        target.IconName = state.Value ? indTrue : indFalse;
    else
        target.IconName = indDisconnected;
}
```

Caling method `device.ReadData()` lasts too long so when it was on GUI thread it makes application unusable even it seemed it runs just few miliseconds when I didn't use `AddIdle`.

Without `AddIdle` the update did not run on GUI thread and when one refresh did not finished before next timer event elapsed was raised then it could update the same objects and the exception was raised.